# .closest in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to target closest div from my anchor tag. so in order do so i have made one small function but it is not working and i also want one div show at one time having id "information".

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<style type="text/css">


.frm { float:left; width:700px;}


.information { display:none}

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function (){


    $('.frm').find('a').each(function (){

        $(this).click(function (){

        $(this).closest('div').css ('display','block')


            }
        )

        })

    })


</script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="frm">
<ul>

<li>heading</li>
<li>paragraph</li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>

</ul>


<div class="information">

<h6>jitender</h6>
<p>containg data</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="frm">
<ul>

<li>heading</li>
<li>paragraph</li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>

</ul>


<div class="information">

<h6>jitender</h6>
<p>containg data</p>

</div>

</div>


</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I know, the name is somewhat confusing, but `closest(x)` actually means "closest parent node matching rule x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/twzuq/

```
$('.frm a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('.information').hide(); // make sure all .information divs are hidden
   $(this).closest('ul').next('.information').show(); // show the .information div nearest the link
});​
```

As mentioned in the comments, [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses through the current elements' ancestors to find the element that matches the selector. So, here I find the UL that contains the clicked link, and then I use [`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next element that has the `.information` class.

Also, `.show` and `.hide` set `display` = `none` and `block` (or `inline`, if the element is inline), respectively. A shortcut for using `.css('display','none')`.

Comment: thanks sir it work fine, i have a question can we give direct id in closest like: $(this).closest('ul#new').next('.information').show();

Comment: Yes, that would work (or simply `$(this).closest('#new')...`. If the `id` is unique for each section, all you'd have to do is `$('#myuniqueid').next('.information').show();`.